Need to Capture active tab audio using extension and add captions in sync
I am trying to capture my browser audio using TabCapture, but I am getting the below error and am unable to capture the audio from the active tab.
let audioStream;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.message === "check_tab_capture") {
        sendResponse({ exists: !!chrome.tabCapture });
    } else if (request.message === "start_capture") {
        if (chrome.tabCapture) {
            chrome.tabCapture.capture({ audio: true }, (stream) => {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    console.error("Error capturing tab audio:", chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                    sendResponse({ success: false, error: chrome.runtime.lastError.message });
                    return;
                }
                audioStream = stream;
                console.log("Audio stream captured:", stream);
                sendResponse({ success: true });
            });
        } else {
            console.error("tabCapture API is not available.");
            sendResponse({ success: false, error: "tabCapture API is not available." });
        }
        return true; // Keep the message channel open for asynchronous response
    } else if (request.message === "stop_capture") {
        if (audioStream) {
            audioStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
            audioStream = null;
            console.log("Audio capture stopped.");
            sendResponse({ success: true });
        } else {
            sendResponse({ success: false, error: "No active capture to stop." });
        }
    } else {
        sendResponse({ success: false, error: "Unknown command." }); // Handle unknown commands
    }
});{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Tab Capture Checker",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
      "tabCapture"
  ],
  "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "host_permissions":[
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*",
      "<all_urls>"
    ]
}document.getElementById('startCapture').addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "start_capture" }, (response) => {
        if (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                console.log("Capture started successfully.");
            } else {
                console.error("Capture failed:", response.error);
            }
        } else {
            console.error("No response received from the background script.");
        }
    });
});

document.getElementById('stopCapture').addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "stop_capture" }, (response) => {
        if (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                console.log("Capture stopped successfully.");
            } else {
                console.error("Stop capture failed:", response.error);
            }
        } else {
            console.error("No response received from the background script.");
        }
    });
});<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tab Capture Checker</title>
    <script src="popup.js" defer></script> <!-- Use defer to ensure the script runs after the DOM is loaded -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tab Capture API Checker</h1>
    <button id="startCapture">Start Capture</button>
    <button id="stopCapture" disabled>Stop Capture</button>
</body>
</html>




Error in event handler: TypeError: chrome.tabCapture.capture is not a function at chrome-extension://kfemjdohcipdogcflpipihilhcgdaiib/background.js:8:31
No response received from the background script.
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
